# Lazy regex using Bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I'm trying to match just the text contained within the HTML tags using Bash's built-in regex function:

```
string='<span class="circle"> </span>foo</span></span>'
regex='<span class="circle"> </span>(.+?)</span>'
[[ $string =~ $regex ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

But the match keeps capturing `foo</span>`.

The internet is so crowded with examples of sed and grep that I haven't found much documentation on Bash's own regex.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question about lazy regexes in bash, but you can match just `foo` if you change `$regex` to `'<span class="circle"> </span>([^<>]+?)</span>'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a reason why the internet is packed with alternative approaches. I can't really think of any situation where you would be *forced* to use bash for this. Why not use one of the tools designed for the job?

Anyway, as far as I know there is no way of doing non-greedy matches using the `=~` operator. That's because it does not use bash's internal regex engine but your system's C one as defined in `man 3 regex`. This is explained in `man bash`:

```
   An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the  same  prece‐
   dence  as  ==  and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of the
   operator is considered  an  extended  regular  expression  and  matched
   accordingly  (as  in  regex(3)).
```

You can, however, do more or less what you want (bearing in mind that this is really *not* a good way of parsing HTML files) with a slightly different regex:

```
string='<span class="circle"> </span>foo</span></span>'
regex='<span class="circle"> </span>([^<]+)</span>'
[[ $string =~ $regex ]]; 
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

The above will return `foo` as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if bash's regular expressions to non-greedy matching like Perl, so use a Perl regex engine:

```
$ grep -oP '<span class="circle"> </span>\K.+?(?=</span>)' <<<"$string"
foo
```